# Replace dot to underscore in js object keys names

Tags: javascript, key

I need to walk js object and replace all dots to underscores in this object keys.
For example

```
{a.a:"test"}
to
{a_a:"test"}
```

This is my code.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(match).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
    if(val.indexOf(".") != -1){
       val.replace(/\./g,'_');
    }
});
```

Thanks, but I have problem in object not so simple, 
like this

```
{
"a.a":{
   "nee.cc":"sdkfhkj"
},
"b.b": "anotherProp"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4), here's a function that will recursively replace the dots with underscores for each of the object's keys.

And added a test to verify results.

```js
function replaceDotWithUnderscore(obj) {
  _.forOwn(obj, (value, key) => {

    // if key has a period, replace all occurences with an underscore
    if (_.includes(key, '.')) {
      const cleanKey = _.replace(key, /\./g, '_');
      obj[cleanKey] = value;
      delete obj[key];
    }

    // continue recursively looping through if we have an object or array
    if (_.isObject(value)) {
      return replaceDotWithUnderscore(value);
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

// --------------------------------------------------
// Run the function with a test to verify results
// -------------------------------------------------

var input = {
  "a.a": {
    "nee.cc": "sdkfhkj"
  },
  "b.b": "anotherProp"
};

var result = replaceDotWithUnderscore(input);

// run a quick test to make sure our result matches the expected results...
var expectedResult = {
  "a_a": {
    "nee_cc": "sdkfhkj"
  },
  "b_b": "anotherProp"
};

console.log(result);
console.assert(_.isEqual(result, expectedResult), 'result should match expected result.');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new object using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, and replace the the dot in the props's names using a simple string replace without regexp:

```js
function transformKeys(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(o, prop) {
    var value = obj[prop];
    var newProp = prop.replace('.', '_');
    o[newProp] = value;
    return o;
  }, {});
}

var result = transformKeys({"a.a":"test", "b.b": "anotherProp"});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function for loop your object and check has object , then reuse function .

```
var obj = {
"a.a":{
   "nee.cc":"sdkfhkj"
},
"b.b": "anotherProp"
};

d_u(obj); // change dot to underscore function

function d_u(obj){
    for(var i in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[i] == "object") d_u(obj[i]);            
            obj[i.replace(/\./g,'_')] = obj[i];            
            delete obj[i];  // delete old object [current]      
    }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code might help you resolving your issue.

```
Object.keys(yourObj).forEach(function(v){
    yourObj[v.replace(".", "_")] = yourObj[v];
    delete yourObj[v];
    console.log(yourObj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just populate a new object with properties whose keys are with "_" rather than "." :

```
var transformKeys = obj => {
  result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => {
    var y = x.replace(".", "_");
    result[y] = obj[x];
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(transformKeys({"a.a":"test", "b.b": "anotherProp"}));
// { a_a: 'test', b_b: 'anotherProp' }
```